# SQLite doesn't run and no error

Tags: php, sqlite

I wanted to run SQLite on my new website but it doesn't run/work.
`PHPINFO()` returns the following information about SQLite:

```
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
PECL Module version     1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6.2.2 2007/03/23 14:30:00 wez Exp $
SQLite Library  3.4.2 

SQLite
SQLite support  enabled
PECL Module version     2.0-dev $Id: sqlite.c,v 1.166.2.13.2.9 2007/05/19 17:58:22 iliaa Exp $
SQLite Library  2.8.17
SQLite Encoding     UTF-8
```

Here the test script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    $db = sqlite_open('mysqlitedb');
    var_dump($db);
    var_dump(sqlite_last_error());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

> ```
> // Output:
> // bool(false) NULL
> ```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Please see [`sqlite_last_error`](http://php.net/sqlite_last_error) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it work?

The [`sqlite_last_error`](http://php.net/sqlite_last_error) function expects the database resource handle as the first parameter, you do not use it:

```
var_dump(sqlite_last_error());
```

Additionally your database resource handle is obviously false - so not a database resource handle at all. As there is no database connection established, that function can not give you the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
sqlite_open('mysqlitedb', 0666, $sqliteerror)
```

that way you can retrieve the reason why it did not work via $sqlliteerror variable.